# Automate entering a password two times

Tags: bash, shell

How can I automate entering a password two times?

Example:

When I run `mkstore -wrl -create ( oracle create wallet command )` it needs the password two times.

If it needed it just once I could do it like this:

```
echo 'dummypassword' | mkstore -wrl -create
```

However, since I must enter it two times, the following does not work:

```
echo 'dummypassword' | echo 'dummypassword' | mkstore -wrl -create
```

Comment: `echo 'dummypassword\ndummypassword'` may help

Answer (score 1):

Use `$'...'` to embed a newline:

```
echo $'dummypassword\ndummypassword' | mkstore -wrl -create
```

Run `echo` twice:

```
{ echo 'dummypassword'; echo 'dummypassword'; } | mkstore -wrl -create
```

Use `yes` to print the password over and over, and `head` to limit the number of repetitions:

```
yes 'dummypassword' | head -n 2 | mkstore -wrl -create
```

Comment: or `mkstore -wrl -create <<<$'dummypassword\ndummypassword'`

Comment: or `mkstore -wrl -create < <(head -n2 < <(tee /dev/stdin <<<'password'))`